# IEXTrading API php class

Tags: php, api

Good day, I'm trying to import stock quotes using IEX Trading API.
I founded some php classes to use those apis but I'm having troubles in intalling them:

In my index.php page I'm including the main class file:
`include("DPRMC/IEXTrading/src/IEXTrading.php");`

no problems here, the inclusion works (o tried echoing a variable and is actually printed on screen)

in the IEXTrading.php file I have this code:

```
namespace DPRMC\IEXTrading;

use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Exceptions\InvalidStockChartOption;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Exceptions\ItemCountPassedToStockNewsOutOfRange;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Exceptions\UnknownSymbol;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockChart;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockCompany;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockFinancials;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockLogo;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockNews;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockPeers;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockPrice;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockQuote;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockRelevant;
use DPRMC\IEXTrading\Responses\StockStats;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;


class IEXTrading { ............ }
```

but when in my index.php page I call

```
$stockQuote = IEXTrading::stockQuote( 'aapl' );
echo $stockQuote->companyName; // Apple Inc.
```

I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'IEXTrading' not found

any help?

Answer (score 0):

If the classes you are using is [DPRMC/IEXTrading](https://github.com/DPRMC/IEXTrading)
you can manage it via composer, using [its composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/dprmc/iex-trading).

You have to:

1. install [PHP composer](https://getcomposer.org/),
2. In your project folder install the package with this command:

   ```
   composer require dprmc/iex-trading
   ```
3. Add the composer requirement in your PHP file:

   ```
   require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   ```
4. Use functions:

**Quote**

```
    // https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#quote 
    $stockQuote = IEXTrading::stockQuote( 'aapl' );
    echo $stockQuote->companyName; // Apple Inc.
```

Let me know :-)